# Symfony doctrine batch processing not working

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, batch-processing

Maybe anyone can have a look:

I have a function and using batch to process bulk data to doctrine, but it not seems working, because nothing is inserted to database, but if i flush() every element, everything is working

any ideas why?

```
private function insertData($linesInFile, $output)

    {

        $google = $this->getContainer()->get('google.books');
        $amazon = $this->getContainer()->get('amazon.books');
        $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $number = 1;
        $batchSize = 5;


        foreach ($linesInFile as $string) {
            $string = preg_split('/isbn_13/', $string);
            $book = new Book();
            $isbn = new Isbn();

            if (isset($string[1])) {
                $value = str_split($string[1], 23);
                $isbnValue = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $value[0]);

                $isbn->setIsbn($isbnValue);

                $book = $google->getBookByIsbn($isbn);
                if (null == $book->getIsbn()) {
                    $book = $amazon->getBookByIsbn($isbn);
                }
                $pages = $book->getPages();
                $image = $book->getCover();
                $about = $book->getAbout();

                if ($about !== "") {
                    if ($image !=="") {
                        $em->persist($book);
                        if (($number % $batchSize) === 0) {
                            $em->flush();
                            $em->clear();
                        }
                        $output->writeln($isbnValue);
                        $number++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $em->flush();
        $em->clear();
        return $number;
    }
}
```

Comment: So how does the code look if you not flush every element?

Comment: I paste code with batch = 5 (flush with every 5 persist)

Comment: Your code looks right.  No error messages?  $isbnValues being written out? Are you sure nothing else is going one which might delete the database?  What happens if you die($number) instead of return $number;

Comment: Are you sure that the persist method is called ? Check in your `app/log/dev.log` files what queries are executed by your script.

Comment: are all the `if`s satisfied! Given theres no problem with your code, may be its just not satisfying all those `if`s

Answer (score 0):

So, my code is good, it was some bug in google API and items were not persisted properly.